# How to test scope parent function in directive using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, parent, directive

I'm working on the Jasmine unit test for Angular directive. And I have a parent function who used in my directive, how to test it? My code is as below:

1. This is half of my directive:

   ```
               link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
               scope.cancel=function(){
                   scope.deleteConfig=false;
                   scope.$parent.$parent.deleteMode=false;
                   $('#window-block').remove();
                   $('#confirm-delete-modal').remove();
               };

               scope.submit = function(){
                   scope.deleteConfig=false;
                   scope.$parent.$parent.deleteMode=false;
           scope.$parent.deleteModeConfig(scope.analytic,scope.config);
                   $('#window-block').remove();
                   $('#confirm-delete-modal').remove();
               };
   ```
2. This is part of my unit testing for this piece of code:

   ```
   it('should remove modal on cancel', function() {
       isolatedScope.cancel();
   });

   it('should submit modal on submit', function() {
       isolatedScope.submit();
   });
   ```

The end is the first cancel function passed the test, but the submit function is failed, the error is: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'scope.$parent.deleteModeConfig(scope.analytic,scope.config)')

Anyone could help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not answering but had to be said:
It's not a very good practise to use parent scopes. You should isolate the scope and give a function via an attribute to manipulate that property. If you have many properties to manipulate pass a single object through an attribute which contains all the necessary functions. When you test it you just give a mock of the method/configuration object and verify the calls

Answer:
The way you test it in your code is to create a mock of the parent scope that contains a property of parent scope itself that contains the property you wish to check.